# New build - DisplayPort no signal but HDMI working

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, displayport

I just completed a new PC build, I've done quite a few so I'm experienced enough. To my surprise, there is no signal coming from either of the 3 displayPorts on the Zotac 1070Ti graphics card, but the HDMI is providing a signal. I've set up the machine as normal with Windows 10 and installed all drivers. Initially I thought I might need to install display drivers to make the DP ports work, but after I did and restarted the DPs still don't output signal.

Card is: Zotac 1070Ti Mini
Monitor: AOC Q2778VQE monitor

Any ideas or suggestions on what the problem could be?

Comment: Have you installed the [Zotac driver](https://www.zotac.com/us/files/download/graphics_cards?driver_type=235&g_card_series=1534&g_card_os=981&sku=ZT-P10710G-10P&skuSelect=ZT-P10710G-10P)? Have you considered that the card might be defective?

Comment: Yep, sorry I didn't make it clear enough, I installed ZOTAC GeForce Graphic driver 411.63 for Win 10 64bits and restarted but the DPs still don't work.

Comment: How do you know that the card is not defective?

Comment: Did you actually enable those outputs from the display control panel?

Comment: @harrymc I don't, that's what I'll have to go with once I've eliminated all other possibilities.

Comment: @EugenRieck I didn't try that. The PC I build before the DPs always worked, I will try that later, thanks.

Comment: @PaulRedmond if the HDMI output is the primary output and the DP ports are secondaries, they will not start output from BIOS but will need to be enabled by the driver. The display control panel will do that.

Comment: @EugenRieck Interesting, I didn't know that. I'll try this later and report back.